# How to get delimiter count as a input?

Tags: c#, delimiter

in the program, i have to handle a input table like this.

```
a:1
b:2
c:3
?:6
#:14
```

obviously, delimiter is ":" and "\n"

however, input like this will catch an exception

```
::2
```

I want to make ':' store into a char list as well.

how do i modify these code?
and where should I put try-catch in?

```
String[] str;
str = textbox.Text.Trim().Split(':', '\n');

for (i = 0; i < str.Length; i = i + 2){
    char tempC;
    float tempFreq;

    if (char.TryParse(str[i], out tempC))
        c.Add(tempC);

    if (float.TryParse(str[i + 1], out tempFreq))
        freq.Add(tempFreq);

}
```

Comment: "Split and keep delimiters in result" is quite common question - if your goal is different please make sure clearly specify what is special about your case in new question.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse your text line by line.Use the `Lines` property for that

Then you can just check if the current line starts with `:`

```
var lines = textbox.Lines;

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    if(line.StartsWith(':')) 
    { 
        c.Add(':');
        float tempFreq;
        if (float.TryParse(line.Split(':').Last(), out tempFreq))
             freq.Add(tempFreq);
    }
    else
    {
       char tempC;
       float tempFreq;
       string[] parts = line.Split(':');
       if (char.TryParse(parts[0], out tempC))
           c.Add(tempC);

       if (float.TryParse(parts[1], out tempFreq))
          freq.Add(tempFreq);
    } 
}
```

Btw, I assumed it is `WinForms`, `Lines` property might not exist in `WPF`, if that is the case just split the text by newline character first, then iterate over the lines and do the same things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, you can also split the lines first.

Your sample data with edge cases

```
var text = @"a:1
b:2
c:3
?:6
::2
#:14  ";
```

LINQ query which selects the char and the float as pair:

```
float freq = 0;
string[] lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var lineTokens = lines.Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length == 2 && arr[0].Trim().Length == 1 && float.TryParse(arr[1].Trim(), out freq))
    .Select(arr => new { chr = arr[0].Trim()[0], freq });
```

Output:

```
foreach(var x in lineTokens)
    Console.WriteLine("Char:{0} Frequency:{1}", x.chr, x.freq);

Char:a Frequency:1
Char:b Frequency:2
Char:c Frequency:3
Char:? Frequency:6
Char:# Frequency:14
```